# generic and generic map | total time delay for each files

Tags: vhdl

In adder.vhd

```
  H1: half_Adder generic map ( gate_delay => 6 ns );      
  port map ( a => ln1, b => ln2, ... );
```

half_adder.vhd

```
  Ex1 : xor generic map ( gate_delay => gate_delay );
  A1  : and generic map ( gate_delay => gate_delay );
```

and.vhd

```
  entity and is generic ( gate_delay : Time := 2 ns );
```

xor.vhd

```
  entity xor is generic ( gate_delay : Time := 3 ns );
```

I gave four files.

My question is, how much should one wait to see correct result ? In other words, what is the total time delay for each file?

Comment: If one doesn't understand what I try to ask, feel free when you say something

Comment: Are you asking which definition of "gate_delay" will take precedence? The value from half_adder's generic map will be passed down into 'and' and 'xor'.

Answer (score 1):

Since the longest path in [a half adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29#Half_adder) is only one gate, the delay of the entire circuit will be equal to the gate delay. In this case, the gate delay is 6 ns. The default values for `gate_delay` of both gate entities are overridden in the instantiations you write.

Note that your code will not work since `and` and `xor` are reserved words in VHDL. You will need to rename to something like `and_gate` and `xor_gate`

Another side note: VHDL code like this is only used for gate level *simulation* with timing annotations, usually after synthesis and place and route. If you want to write an adder in VHDL, you should write `a <= b + c;`